# Spring JPA OneToMany with composite Key mapping

Tags: java, jpa, mapping

I am having issues mapping the following using spring JPA. Let's say I have a order table which has two primary keys. one is a foreign key to customer and another is a foreign key to order Type as seen below:

```
Customer
+----+------+--+
| id*| name |  |
+----+------+--+
|  1 | Joe  |  |
+----+------+--+

Order
+------------+-------------+
| customerId | orderTypeId |
+------------+-------------+
|          1 |           1 |
+------------+-------------+

OrderType
+----+--------+
| id |  type  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | online |
+----+--------+
```

the idea is each customer has a one to many relationship with Orders. the primary key of orders is a combination of the two foreign keys.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite-associations

Comment: This has nothing to do with spring. I tried to pick some more fitting tags.